# upload an image using PHP to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to upload an image using PHP to MySQL. In the query i'm trying to save the image and the  directory of the image in the DB, but I get empty directory in the DB, plus no image in the folder. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
// include db connect class
 define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once(__ROOT__.'/android_connect/db_connect.php');

 $db = new DB_CONNECT();


//Setting up images directory
 $target = "./images"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

 $photo=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

//inserting data order
$order = "INSERT INTO scb
        (photo, directory)
        VALUES
        (  '$_POST[$target]',
        '({$_FILES['photo']['name']})')";  

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information  has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives an error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 

//declare in the order variable
$result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
if($result){
echo "Thank you for submitting!";
} else{
echo "Sorry, something went wrong! Please try again!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey, Make sure you have appropriate access to the folder where you are trying to upload. Also you can get an error by printing out the value of:
$_FILES["photo"]["error"]

Comment: Check for errors and also, check form (please provide form html, too).

Comment: I'm using an android app to upload the image, I've used another code to upload the image to the folder and it works, but when I wanted to save the Image to Mysql I get this error" Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file." which means that the image is not uploaded!I will try to print out the value of : $_FILES["photo"]["error"] and get back to you guys

Comment: just echo $_FILES['photo']['error'] in the else section.

Comment: No error showed up, when I tried!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first `mysql_query` is outdated use `PDO` instead (you'll have to check if this feature is enabled on your server by using `phpinfo()`);

Try this

```
    <?php 
            //Connect to sql db
            try {
                    $user = "username";
                    $pass = "password";
                    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdb', $user, $pass);

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
                    die();
            }



            //Setting up images directory
            $target = "./images/";  //you forgot the last slash 
            $target = $target . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

            $photo = $_FILES['photo']['name']; 

            //inserting data order
            $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO scb (photo, directory) VALUES (:photo, :directory)");
            $stmt->bindParam(':photo', $_POST[$target]);
            $stmt->bindParam(':directory', $_FILES['photo']['name']);


            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
            { 

                    //Tells you if its all ok 
                    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information  has been added to the directory"; 
            } 
            else { 

                    //Gives an error if its not 
                    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
            } 

            //declare in the order variable
            if($stmt->execute()){
                    echo "Thank you for submitting!";
            } else{
                    echo "Sorry, something went wrong! Please try again!";
            }
    ?>
```

Comment: Got this error Error!: SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'a5983957****'@'10.1.1.22' to database ' a5983957***' any idea how to deal with it?

Comment: Check your host, db name,usename,and password

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for any errors or warnings in the web server log files? Do you get any sensible output if you write:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```